# How can I check if a value has even parity of bits or odd?

Tags: c, bit

A value has [even parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) if it has an even number of '1' bits. A value has an odd parity if it has an odd number of '1' bits. For example, `0110` has even parity, and `1110` has odd parity.

I have to return `1` if `x` has even parity.

```
int has_even_parity(unsigned int x) {
    return
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bit parity code for odd number of bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530599/bit-parity-code-for-odd-number-of-bits)

Comment: See here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/21589674/even-parity-of-a-unsigned-int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589674/even-parity-of-a-unsigned-int).

Comment: The more general (and slower) case is *[Count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)*

Comment: A 2010 question: *[What is the fastest way for bit operations to calculate a parity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208646/what-is-the-fastest-way-for-bit-operations-to-calculate-a-parity)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
int has_even_parity(unsigned int x){
    unsigned int count = 0, i, b = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        if( x & (b << i) ){count++;}
    }

    if( (count % 2) ){return 0;}

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 95):

```
x ^= x >> 16;
x ^= x >> 8;
x ^= x >> 4;
x ^= x >> 2;
x ^= x >> 1;
return (~x) & 1;
```

Assuming you know ints are 32 bits.

---

Let's see how this works. To keep it simple, let's use an 8 bit integer, for which we can skip the first two shift/XORs. Let's label the bits *a* through *h*. If we look at our number we see:

( *a* *b* *c* *d* *e* *f* *g* *h* )

---

The first operation is `x ^= x >> 4` (remember we're skipping the first two operations since we're only dealing with an 8-bit integer in this example). Let's write the new values of each bit by combining the letters that are XOR'd together (for example, *ab* means the bit has the value *a* xor *b*).

( *a* *b* *c* *d* *e* *f* *g* *h* )
xor
( *0* *0* *0* *0* *a* *b* *c* *d* )

The result is the following bits:

( *a* *b* *c* *d* *ae* *bf* *cg* *dh* )

---

The next operation is `x ^= x >> 2`:

( *a* *b* *c* *d* *ae* *bf* *cg* *dh* )
xor
( 0 0 *a* *b* *c* *d* *ae* *bf* )

The result is the following bits:

( *a* *b* *ac* *bd* *ace* *bdf* *aceg* *bdfh* )

Notice how we are beginning to accumulate all the bits on the right-hand side.

---

The next operation is `x ^= x >> 1`:

( *a* *b* *ac* *bd* *ace* *bdf* *aceg* *bdfh* )
xor
( 0 *a* *b* *ac* *bd* *ace* *bdf* *aceg* )

The result is the following bits:

( *a* *ab* *abc* *abcd* *abcde* *abcdef* *abcdefg* *abcdefgh* )

---

We have accumulated all the bits in the original word, XOR'd together, in the least-significant bit. So this bit is now zero if and only if there were an even number of 1 bits in the input word (even parity). The same process works on 32-bit integers (but requires those two additional shifts that we skipped in this demonstration).

The final line of code simply strips off all but the least-significant bit (`& 1`) and then flips it (`~x`). The result, then, is 1 if the parity of the input word was even, or zero otherwise.

Comment: The final line of code flips bits and then strips the other bits (your explanation has those two the other way around)

Comment: And for an 8-bit value it would only be with the last three XOR lines (instead of the five XOR lines)?

Comment: campared to understand it, I'd rather want to know how to invent it.

Answer (score 12):

GCC has [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for this:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_parity (unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the parity of `x`, i.e. the number of 1-bits in x modulo 2.

and similar functions for `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`.

I.e. this function behaves like `has_odd_parity`. Invert the value for `has_even_parity`.

These should be the fastest alternative on GCC. Of course its use is not portable as such, but you can use it in your implementation, guarded by a macro for example.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel in different shapes and sizes I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 9):

The following answer was unashamedly lifted directly from [Bit Twiddling Hacks By Sean Eron Anderson, seander@cs.stanford.edu](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

**Compute parity of word with a multiply**

> The following method computes the parity of the 32-bit value in only 8 operations >using a multiply.

```
unsigned int v; // 32-bit word
v ^= v >> 1;
v ^= v >> 2;
v = (v & 0x11111111U) * 0x11111111U;
return (v >> 28) & 1;
```

> Also for 64-bits, 8 operations are still enough.

```
unsigned long long v; // 64-bit word
v ^= v >> 1;
v ^= v >> 2;
v = (v & 0x1111111111111111UL) * 0x1111111111111111UL;
return (v >> 60) & 1;
```

> Andrew Shapira came up with this and sent it to me on Sept. 2, 2007.

Answer (score 2):

To generalise [TypeIA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617970/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-has-even-parity-of-bits-or-odd/21618038#21618038) for any architecture:

```
int has_even_parity(unsigned int x) 
{
    unsigned char shift = 1;
    while (shift < (sizeof(x)*8))
    {
        x ^= (x >> shift);
        shift <<= 1;
    }
    return !(x & 0x1);
}
```

Comment: This isn't for any architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is this. Unset the rightmost '1' bit by using `x & ( x - 1 )`. Let’s say x = 13(1101) and the operation of `x & ( x - 1 )`  is `1101 & 1100` which is 1100, notice that the rightmost set bit is converted to `0`.

Now `x` is `1100`. The operation of `x & ( x - 1 )`, i.e., `1100 & 1011` is `1000`. Notice that the original `x` is `1101` and after two operations of `x & (x - 1)` the `x` is `1000`, i.e., two set bits are removed after two operations. If after an *odd* number of operations, the `x` becomes zero, then it's an odd parity, else it's an even parity.

Comment: Use the following link if you need more explanation and code:[geeks for geeks link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-parity-of-an-unsigned-integer/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **one line `#define`** that does the trick for a `char`:

```
#define PARITY(x) ((~(x ^= (x ^= (x ^= x >> 4) >> 2) >> 1)) & 1) /* even parity */

int main()
{
    char x=3;
    printf("parity = %d\n", PARITY(x));
}
```

It's portable as heck and easily modified to work with bigger words (16, 32 bit). It's important to note also, using a `#define` speeds the code up, each function call requires time to push the stack and allocate memory. Code size doesn't suffer, especially if it's implemented only a few times in your code - the function call might take up as much object code as the XORs.

Admittedly, the same efficiencies may be obtained by using the **inline** function version of this, `inline char parity(char x) {return PARITY(x);}` (GCC) or `__inline char parity(char x) {return PARITY(x);}` (MSVC). Presuming you keep the one line define.

Comment: This isn't strictly correct, it should be used for *unsigned chars*, not signed

Comment: Oppsies, you're right, thanks. I won't modify the post though, it'll be trivial for those who use it to fix it _(or not)_.

Answer (score -1):

```
int parity_check(unsigned x) {
    int parity = 0;
    while(x != 0) {
        parity ^= x;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return (parity & 0x1);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

In case the end result is supposed to be a piece of code that can work (be compiled) with a C program then I suggest the following:

```
.code

; bool CheckParity(size_t Result)
    CheckParity PROC
    mov        rax, 0
    add        rcx, 0
    jnp        jmp_over
    mov        rax, 1
jmp_over:
    ret
CheckParity ENDP

END
```

This is a piece of code I'm using to check the parity of calculated results in a 64-bit C program compiled using [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B). You can obviously port it to 32 bit or other compilers.

This has the advantage of being much faster than using C and it also leverages the CPU's functionality.

What this example does is take as input a parameter (passed in RCX - __fastcall calling convention). It increments it by 0 thus setting the CPU's *parity flag* and then setting a variable (RAX) to 0 or 1 if the parity flag is on or not.

Comment: I cannot get this to compile with GCC on Linux (but I know very little assembly). Would you please provide a hint on how to embed this in a C program?

Comment: The parity computed by the x86 CPUs is based only on the bits in the lower byte of the destination register, not the entire register.

Comment: Plus `add rcx,0` is an unfortunate choice to update flags, just `test ecx,ecx` would be enough (`ecx`, because parity flag is calculated from 8 bits only any way, so it doesn't matter what part of `rcx` you test, and `ecx` is short machine code). And `jnp` is slower than `setp` without jumps. And usually most of the C compilers will have built-in intrinsic function, which is definitely best (and fastest) choice, to avoid some small bug in 3 lines code... (like demonstrated here).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883473/working-inline-assembly-in-c-for-bit-parity/43929095#43929095 for an analysis of why this sucks even if you fixed it to work for the whole 64 bits, and for much better ways to compute parity on x86. (With benchmarks on Haswell)