# how parity works to find even or odd 1's bit?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to find out the number of bit 1 is odd or even.
Here is the code:

```
int odd_ones(unsigned x)
{

    x ^= x >> 16;
    x ^= x >> 8;
    x ^= x >> 4;
    x ^= x >> 2;
    x ^= x >> 1;
    return !(x&1);
}
```

But I don't know how it works; I've been stuck at this for long time.

Comment: Do you understand what `>>`, `&` and `^` are? If no, that's why you don't get it, if yes, tell us where you stuck.

Comment: >> stand for right shirt
& for AND
^ stand for XOR.
I wrote down all under bit represent, it give the true answer but i don't know how it can give it???

Comment: `odd_ones()` returns the opposite value that I would expect for it functions like this: `odd_ones(0)` --> 1 and `odd_ones(1)` --> 0.  I'd rename this function `is_even_parity()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618038/631612

Answer (score 6):

Try to prove that after doing `x ^= x >> 16;` the last 16 bits of `x` will have the same parity of `1`s as the original value `x`(assuming x is 32 bit). Then after doing `x ^= x >> 8;` the last **8** bits of x will have the same parity of `1`-s as the last 16 bits of x **before** the operation. As a rule when you do `x ^= x >> L`, the last `L` bits of the result will have the same parity of `1`s as the parity of `1`s in last `2*L` bits of the original value of x.

Comment: Now I understand a little, but How can I prove after doing x^= x >> L, the last L bits of the resultt will have the same parity of 1s as the parity of 1s in last 2*L ???

Comment: It is a nice exercise for bit manipulation. I will do you no good if I give you the answer.

Comment: Ok, it from CSAPP, I will think harder this time. thanks for your help

Comment: Because 1 ^ 1 = 0, then when i use XOR in x ^= x >> L, it simply delete   2*i number of bit 1. That why the last L bits have the same parity of x.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a circuit diagram of an **8-bit parity generator**. 
Your code tries to implement this combinatorial circuit to a sequential logic (for 32-bits).

Imagining the working of this circuit would help you understand the code.

[image]

The equivalent code for above circuit i.e. for 8-bits would be:

```
int odd_ones(unsigned x)
{
    x ^= x >> 1;
    x ^= x >> 2;
    x ^= x >> 4;
    return !(x&1);
}
```

*image courtesy [Brigham Young University](https://www.byu.edu/)*